# Null Values In Linq to sql

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have table called Customers and this customer has Bank Details
but Some customer they don't have,

When i Use Linq to sql it's Return Null value,  like  a below example Table

How to prevent this null into Default value 0 or String

Ex. Table

```
Customer ID   Name            bank name
-----------   ------          --------------
J0002         John            HSBC 
K0001         Kethy           SMC
L0003         Mike            Null
S0004         Lilie           Null
```

Thanks

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
var customers = (from c in Customers
                        select new Customer
                       (
                          c.CustomerId, 
                          c.Name, 
                          c.BankName ?? ""
                       )).ToList();
```

or

```
var result = Customer.Select(x => new
{
    CustomerId = x.CustomerId,
    Name = x.Name,
    BankName = x.BankName.HasValue ? x.BankName : ""
}).OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToArray();
```

could do the trick. It would be easier if you showed your current query.

Comment: I'm not really a VB.NET programmer but if you send your query I might be able to modify it to your needs.

Comment: Check out `If(c.BankName Is Nothing, "", c.BankName)`